# WCF wsHttpBinding : Avoiding multiple "ISSUE" calls while calling a web service using wsHttpBinding

Tags: wcf, web-services, wcf-binding, wshttpbinding

I am using `wsHttpBinding` to call a WCF web service. When I look into the Fiddler2, I see multiple calls to the server before calling my actual `OperationContract`.

From [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/socaldevgal/archive/2007/08/15/why-is-wshttpbinding-secure-by-default-how-does-it-work.aspx) I understood what these service calls are doing.

**However, I want to know if there is any way to avoid these calls after first successful service call.**

In my application, the web service is called so frequently that 3-4 additional calls per actual call to web service operation will not be accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioend what happens is that WCF negotiates for a key. More details [in here](http://webservices20.blogspot.co.il/2009/01/wcf-performance-gearing-up-your-service.html).

You have a few options:

- set negotiateServerCredential and establishSecurityContext to false (this would require the client to have the server certificate out of band)
- change to a different security mechanism (user name auth, or transport with SSL)
- stay with the current situation. Once the negotiation is established no more extra calls are made. They happen once per proxy generation.

There is no way to make the negotiation process shorter. It consists of several message exchanges since this is the WS-Trust protocol.

Comment: I opted the last option. I create instance of the proxy class and reuse it for all subsequent service calls until the `InnerChannel` goes to the `Closed` or `Faulted` state. Proxy's `InnerChannel` exposes events which are raised when channel is in Closed or Faulted state. I subscribe to those events and recreate proxy instance in the event handler.